# (multidimensional array) Change all values where index is a certain string

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am working with an array such as the following and I'd like to set all the "price" keys, that have no value, to 0.

How can I achieve this, if the depth of the array is infinite?

Big thanks!

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [random_key0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Foo
                [price] => 25
            )

        [random_key1] => Array
            (
                [name] => Bar
                [price] => 
            )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [name] => 125
        [price] =>
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [another_key0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Foo
                [options] => Options here
                [special0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Special Name
                        [price] =>
                    )

                [special1] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Special 2
                        [price] => 120
                    )

              )
        )
  )
```

Comment: I can recommend you instead of looping it to cast prices to int/float when you use it. Empty will become 0..

Comment: Where are you getting the source data from? This would be much easier to do there. Or even on display if that would do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php), for example like this:

```
<?php
function update_price(&$item, $key) {
    if ($key == 'price' && !$item) {
        $item = 0;
    }
}
$test = array('key1' => array('price' => null, 'test' => 'abc', 'sub' => array('price' => 123), 'sub2' => array('price' => null)));
array_walk_recursive($test, 'update_price');
print_r($test);
```

Answer (score 1):

You would do this with a "walking" function, that calls itself until all elements are worked through:

```
<?php
$test = array(
    array(
        "random_key0" => array("name"=>"foo","price"=>25), 
        "random_key1" => array("name"=>"Bar","price"=>"")
    ),
    array("name"=>125,"price"=>""), 
    array("another_key0" => array(
        "name" => "foo",
        "options" => "Options here",
        "special0" => array("name"=>"Special Name","price"=>""),
        "special1" => array("name"=>"Special 2","price"=>120),
    ))
);

function test_alter(&$item, $key)
{
    if ($key=="price" && empty($item))
        $item = 0;
}

function test_print($item2, $key)
{
    echo "$key. $item2<br>\n";
}

echo "Before ...:\n";
array_walk_recursive($test, 'test_print');

// now actually modify values
array_walk_recursive($test, 'test_alter');

echo "... and afterwards:\n";
array_walk_recursive($test, 'test_print');
?>
```

Actually i saw i was too slow, but here you got sample for non-modifying recursive function as well :)